# gitフックで対話的処理を行うにはどうすればよいですか？

Tags: python, git

次のようなPythonスクリプトを`commit-msg`に設定して対話処理を行おうと思っているのですが、入力するまもなく`EOFError`になってしまいます。

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

x = input("input your name: ")
print("Hello, " + x)
```

```
% git commit -am"Add test-commit-msg"                                                       master
input your name: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/hooks/commit-msg", line 3, in <module>
    x = input("input your name: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

どのようにすればgitフックで対話処理を実現できるでしょうか？

Comment: [How do I prompt the user from within a commit-msg hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

metropolisさんのコメントを参考に、Ubuntu 16.04では

```
sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty", "r")
```

とすることで上手くいきました。